# How to force a redraw in d3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, graph-visualization

I'm building a force directed diagram using d3.js. Essentially I have 50 nodes, where 49 nodes connect to one in the center. These nodes' distance are dependent on how similar they are to the central node.

Problem: After I click a node, I want d3 to read the csv file corresponding to that node and redraw the graph with that node in the center.  I can't figure out how to force d3 to perform a redraw.

Comment: It's very unclear what you are asking for.  Do you not know how to capture clicks?  Do you not know how to tell once a click has been made which node has been clicked on?  Do you not know how to read a CSV file from d3?  Do you not know how to do a redraw?  If you don't know how to do any of that, I suggest you find a good tutorial.

Comment: Forgive me for being unclear. I can do all the aforementioned things except for the redraw which is where my problem is.

Comment: Well the display of the force layout is updated in the `tick` event handler function. Assuming that you've set the data of the nodes appropriately, you shouldn't need to trigger a redraw explicitly as this is handled in the `tick` handler.

Comment: Thank you Lars. I figured out the problem. The idea you proposed seems very valuable as well. I appreciate the help you've provided